# If more than x, their values are

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, discord, discord.js

Hello I want to do something in my bot and I couldn't do it, I want your help. What I want to do is "put this in the status of the bot if the players are greater than 1" the exact opposite.

The code is here;

```
const presence = async () => {
    let res = await oyuncular("players");
    if (oyuncular >= 1)
    client.user.setPresence({activity: {name: `Sunucuda ${res.data.length} kişi`,type:"PLAYING"}, status:"dnd"}) //{name: `Turnuvada ${res.data.length} kişi`,type:"PLAYING"} --- {activity: {name: `Sunucuda ${res.data.length} kişi`,type:"PLAYING"}, status:"dnd"} --- {activity: {name: `Sunucu Bakımda!`,type:"PLAYING"}, status:"dnd"}
    if (oyuncular <= 1)
    client.user.setPresence({activity: {name: `Sunucu Kapalı`,type:"PLAYING"}, status:"dnd"})
    return;

}
```

Comment: What is not working with the current implementation? And isnt the res variable holding the value you want to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake you are making is you are controlling `oyuncular` in the `if` statement. However, there is no parameter named `oyuncular` inside or outside the function. If you want to control the number of players, you have to get this value first.

I'm not sure what is returning `await oyuncular("players")` but I'm guessing this function returns `players` array. So, if you'd check the array length. You can get the `oyuncuSayisi` (Number of active players.)

So if you could try this this function will work:

```
const presence = async () => {
    let res = await oyuncular("players");
    var oyuncuSayisi = res.data.lenght;
    if (oyuncuSayisi >= 1)
    client.user.setPresence({activity: {name: `Sunucuda ${oyuncuSayisi} kişi`,type:"PLAYING"}, status:"dnd"}) //{name: `Turnuvada ${res.data.length} kişi`,type:"PLAYING"} --- {activity: {name: `Sunucuda ${res.data.length} kişi`,type:"PLAYING"}, status:"dnd"} --- {activity: {name: `Sunucu Bakımda!`,type:"PLAYING"}, status:"dnd"}
    if (oyuncuSayisi <= 1)
    client.user.setPresence({activity: {name: `Sunucu Kapalı`,type:"PLAYING"}, status:"dnd"})
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you add log of the `res` object to your question, please?  under the `let res = await oyuncular("players");` row, `console.log(res);`

Comment: I had already defined the actors here. It attracts the number of people over an IP.

[Ekran Görüntüsü/Screenshot](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/338950244379131904/834036323165143110/unknown.png)

Comment: [I did](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/338950244379131904/834037077573894174/unknown.png)

Comment: I can't see the name of the object. Can you show me the part where the object starts?

Comment: [Here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/338950244379131904/834041391973531678/unknown.png) [Here 2](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/338950244379131904/834041446876184646/unknown.png)

Comment: Is there a platform where we can meet instantly instead of struggling? bkz. Discord

Comment: Okay, add me: Murat / 5#5254